# Git и Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Доброго всем вечера. У меня возник следующий вопрос. Я установил в `Visual Studio 2012` расширение `Visual Studio Tools For Git` для работы с этой системой контроля версий из самой `IDE`. Я в этом новичок поэтому может не понимаю каких то простых вещей. Но когда я открыл `Team Explorer` то никаких упоминаний про `Git` я там не обнаружил, а при нажатии на `Sign Up`  открывается страница браузера с адресом `tfs.visualstudio.com` Но мне-то нужен не `tfs` а `git`. Что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста. 
В идеале мне нужно средство которое позволяло бы мне прямо из `Visual Studio` обновлять, редактировать или еще как-то взаимодействовать со своим  репозиторием на `GitHub.com`. Возможно ли это и если да, то как? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поставьте себе [клиент](http://windows.github.com/) из github.com. Он даст все, что нужно. Он не интегрируется в студию, но сам по себе очень функционален.

Answer (score 0):

А вы сменили Source Control Provider в настройках студии?

Comment: где и как?